# Is Hangar space unlimited?

Tags: pocket-planes

I'm a terrible completionist and I noticed when I scrap my planes, they no longer show up in the Airpedia. If they're kept in the Hangar they do count. If possible I'd like to keep one of each plane but I'm not sure if tha Hangar can hold one of each or what.

Can the hangar hold unlimited planes? I don't notice a limit to them anywhere in the game's UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have over 50 planes in my hangar (stopped counting after that) so I think it's unlimited.

Comment: I think that's enough to store one of each plane, so I'll consider that unlimited enough.